# OAUTH: Yahoo always show shows "User Authorization Page"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, yahoo-api

PS: I'm working with OWIN + OAUTH + [YAHOO OWIN](http://www.beabigrockstar.com/guides/aspnet-mvc-yahoo-login/)

I've been working with Yahoo OAUTH API these days and facing a weird situation:

My web app asks authorization to the user. The user accepts and give asked permissions. Then, let's suppose, he closes the browser and at another time, he opens it in my web site again. I call Yahoo OAUTH API again but, instead of automatically understand that the user already gave me the permission and redirect to my page, Yahoo shows the "User Authorization Page" again. The code is the same and so is my request.

Do you guys know why and what should I do to avoid that annoying behaviour?

By the way, I'm working with Google, LinkedIn and Facebook the exatctely same way and all is fine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that you've got the access token, did you refresh it if it expired?

Comment: Actually im always sending the user to authorizarion screen. Same as doing with other providers.

Comment: Once you get refresh token, you need to use it to refresh expired token. The reason of the problem you meet may be the Yahoo doesn't remember user's choice. Any way, always sending user to authorization screen is not a proper way

Answer (score 1):

For others facing the same problem with YAHOO:

Once you first get the access token, you need to store the oauth_token, oauth_session_handle and the access token secret (not the request token secret).

Let's call "oauth_token" as "Access Token Id".

Then, everytime user accesses your page, you pass them to the api:
oauth_token: contains the stored Access Token Id.
oauth_session_handle: contains the stored session handle
oauth_signature: is the consumer secret concatenated with "&" and access token secret
oauth_signature_method: plaintext

In my case, I used the GET method.

See more at https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-refreshaccesstoken.html

In case of any doubts, just send me a message and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. I'd really appreciate if I can get some help from you, I could not find a way to message you.

Comment: @alax Have you tried the solution I posted? My personal e-mail is marco2250@gmail.com